# Ethics of working in defense

Tags: mussar-ethics, army-military-war

The following is not halacha l'maaseh.

Say I am currently looking for a new role. In my search, I come across a fair number of (US-based) defense contractors that seem to have openings for what I am looking for.

Let's say that this position deals with technologies in actual military use. This would be distinct from someone working on Boeing airliners when Boeing also makes warplanes - I assume this would be entirely permissible. Let's also say that this is a field such as engineering or design that is critical to the operation of military devices. This would be distinct from something like human resources which doesn't directly impact the technologies at all.

What, if any, halachic concerns would arise from someone working in such an industry? I can think of some areas:

- Working on offensive weaponry (and therefore possible complicity in murder?)
- Using your talents to support warfare instead of doing good for the world
- Ethics of the (US?) defense industry in general
- Chilul HaShem maybe?
- Any issues with getting security clearance?
- Would things change if I was working for the IDF/an Israeli contractor?
- Would things change if I was a lot more tangential to the process, such as working in HR or office maintenance?
- What if these weapons were to be used against Jews? Do I need to be concerned with the potential of opposing military groups to have Jewish soldiers? How far removed do I have to be from this, e.g. if the US is fighting a proxy war? (For example, if there are Jews in the Russian army and the US is fighting them, or aiding the Ukrainian army in doing so)
- Do I have to be concerned about collateral damage?
- What happens if this technology gets into the hands of our enemies? Does it matter if it's an enemy of the US or if it's an enemy of the Jewish people or State of Israel?
- Do things change if it's peacetime? What if it's peacetime for the US but not for Israel, such as the situation as of posting time?

Now I have seen answers that one could fight for their country in a war, so I am assuming that would apply to this as well, especially since I wouldn't be risking my life here. If one could risk their life and actively kill for a non-Jewish country, then kal v'chomer one could merely be a bit player in weapons manufacturing.

But I am curious what practical things would apply in this case.

Comment: Maimonides rules explicitly that a Jew may sell weapons to a government, as governments increase order in the world. Rabbi J. David Bleich deals a lot more with the concept of arms sales in *Tradition*, Winter 1982: https://traditiononline.org/review-of-recent-halakhic-periodical-literature-sale-of-arms-cholent-recitation-of-ve-ten-tal-u-matar-by-travellers/

Comment: Seems to be limited to governments in active support of Israel; presumably this would include the US. Which makes sense. (Though it's not discussed what considerations are given to countries that would c"v turn on this...)

Also, the US will often sell arms to countries that are generally hostile to Jews/Israel, such as Saudi Arabia.

Comment: Since you say you have "a fair number" of choices, choose something in line with your scruples.